# how to show Update Progress control on top of all control

Tags: css, asp.net

i use bootstrap control .i set style of progress bar `z-index : 100000;`.
but not progress bar up all control .how can do it?
How can I force the Update Progress control to appear on top?

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePageMethods="true" LoadScriptsBeforeUI="true" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uppMain" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: absolute; background: url(/Style/Engine/images/black-bg.png); top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div style="width: 150px; height: 20px;z-index:100002 !important; position: fixed; left: 50%; margin-left: -75px; top: 50%; margin-top: -10px; text-align: center;">
                    <img id="imgLoading" alt="" src="/Style/Engine/images/loading.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ContentTemplate>
              .......
         </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: @shahrox u need to add `AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1"` to the `uppmain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to answer looking at provided code only. You can easily check z-index of control using developer toolbar/firebug which are coming above the updateprogress and give z-index higher than that to the DIV 
One thing you can try is , give z-index to first DIV in updateprogress control (the div with "position: absolute")